# How can we overwrite java.base/java.lang.Integer from OpenJDK 11 using --patch-module?

Tags: java, java-11, java-module, openjdk-11, bootclasspath

In the JDK-8, we could compile our changed java.lang classes and reconstruct the `rt.jar`. Then we could overwrite java.lang classfiles by augmenting the bootclasspath with `-Xbootclasspath:<yourpathto>/rt.jar`.  Doing this, we could for example make java.lang.Integer be non-final for testing purposes.

In JDK-11, this is different. Patching is done via `--patch-modules` and I can't get it to work. I have done the following:

1. Remove the final modifier and recompiled the java.base module from the openjdk-11 source
2. Added the `--patch-module java.base=<path-to-my-compiled-java.base-directory>`
3. It still fails on `error: cannot inherit from final Integer`. Possibly we can't overwrite the class declarations of JDK source files anymore? That would be strange.
4. I've also tried adding these classfiles to a jar and tried to pass all possible root directories to the `--patch-module` argument
5. I've tried removing the module `package-info.class` from the compiled `java.base` directory and tried explicitly adding `java.base.java.lang.Integer` with `--add-opens`

The [docs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Patching-module-content) aren't really clear on this particular usage.

The entire javac command from maven (I have tried both javac and the maven-compiler-plugin):

`javac -d ./target/classes -classpath <classpathfiles> -sourcepath <sourcefiles> -s ./target/generated-sources/annotations -g -nowarn -target 11 -source 11 -encoding UTF-8 --patch-module=java.base=../runtimejar/mods/src/java.base -Xplugin:Manifold`

(Shortened path names etc. for readability)

What am I missing here? Why can't I modify `java.base/java.lang.Integer` like this?

Comment: Did you try using `--patch-module java.base=../runtimejar/mods/src \ 
../runtimejar/mods/src/java.base/java/lang/Integer.java`?

Comment: @Naman, I just did, still get the same `error: cannot inherit from final Integer`. Shouldn't we patch modules with compiled .class files?

Comment: If you really want to change JDK classes you may better use the sources of JDK, modify it and build your own JDK. You should also consider that there may be better, cleaner ways to achieve what you want instead of modifying `Integer`.

Comment: Remove the `-target` command line parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example from [Project Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#xoverride) models your use-case. Note the use of --patch-module for both javac and java.

> #### `--patch-module`
>
> Developers that checkout java.util.concurrent classes from Doug Lea's CVS will be used to compiling the source files and
> deploying those classes with -Xbootclasspath/p.
>
> -Xbootclasspath/p has been removed, its module replacement is the option --patch-module to override classes in a module. It can also be
> used to augment the contents of module. The *--patch-module* option is
> also supported by javac to compile code "as if" part of the module.
>
> Here's an example that compiles a new version of
> *java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap* and uses it at run-time:
>
> ```
>     javac --patch-module java.base=src -d mypatches/java.base \
>         src/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java
>
>     java --patch-module java.base=mypatches/java.base ...
> ```

Check that your sourcepath aligns with your --patch-module directory i.e., is there a file src/java.base/java/lang/Integar.java and is it in your sourcepath?

### Update

Here is a sample project that demonstrates how to shadow java.lang.Integer: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/6swet2k89vukxbm/patch.zip

Compile:

```
javac --patch-module java.base=src -d mypatches/java.base src/java.base/java/lang/Integer.java
javac --patch-module java.base=mypatches/java.base -d target src/main/java/com/example/MyInteger.java src/main/java/com/example/RunMe.java
```

Run:

```
java --patch-module java.base=mypatches/java.base -classpath target com.example.RunMe
```

Comment: I've seen the example from Jigsaw, I'm a bit lost on how to translate it to my use-case properly. I want to compile my project with a patched `java.base.java.lang.Integer`. The example from Jigsaw only seems to compile the `ConcurrentHashMap`? I also need to compile `javac` with a patched `java.base`. I need to use the new patched `java.lang.Integer` at compile-time as well.

Comment: Just to be clear you are not making an Integer class in package java.base.java.lang, right?

Comment: No, my project doesn't have a java.base.java.lang.Integer.java file. I want to produce similar behaviour to adding a modified `rt.jar` to the bootclasspath. I need to compile and run my project with a patched `java.base.java.lang.Integer` that isn't final.

Comment: @MGG Just so you know, calling it `java.base.java.lang.Integer` is confusing. That implies the _package_ name is `java.base.java.lang`. It would be better to just say something like "the `java.lang.Integer` class from the `java.base` module" or do what stack traces do and use `java.base/java.lang.Integer`. You don't even necessarily have to mention the module since there can only be one `java.lang.Integer` due to the module system prohibiting split packages (and the classes in the `java.base` module, especially those in the `java.lang` package, are widely known).

Comment: @MGG I've updated my post to include a simple example that demonstrates how to shadow java.lang.Integer with --patch-module.

Comment: Great. thank you! This is what I was looking for. I've found the culprit, it doesn't work when I use the compiler plugin `-Xplugin:Manifold`. Otherwise it seems to work finely. Maybe because this loads integer again or something in that direction..

Comment: @MGG No problem. Thanks for posting the issue with Manifold, I've logged issue https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/issues/209 which will be fixed in the next release coming later this week.

Comment: @MGG A “`java.lang.Integer` that isn’t final” sounds you are planning to bring yourself into deep trouble…